# How to change column elements of a matrix for each row without creating a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a matrix and I would like to change the column elements from 0 to 1, vice versa, based on a vector. The first column of the first row should be switched and the 3rd column of the second row be flipped aswell. EG

```
mat <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,1,0),2,3)
ind <- c(1,3)

mat1 <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,1),2,3)
```

I would like to get mat1 from mat,

Thank you

Comment: As the matrix has 2 rows so the index vector should be of length 2

Answer (score 3):

Just use `row/column` indexing

```
mat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(mat)), ind)] <- 1
```

---

Or if we don't want to modify the original object, use `replace`

```
mat1 <- replace(mat, cbind(seq_len(nrow(mat)), ind), 1)
```